# Segfault in bv_rewriter::mk_mul_eq()

Tags: z3

I have a short (4-line) program that terminates with a segmentation fault on one system but not on another.

```
(set-logic QF_FP)
(declare-fun s0 () (_ FloatingPoint 11 53))
(assert (fp.isSubnormal (fp.mul roundNearestTiesToEven s0 s0)))
(check-sat)
```

This program should produce `(sat)`, but Z3 crashes, with the following backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  bv_rewriter::mk_mul_eq (this=this@entry=0x1654380, lhs=lhs@entry=0x16149e8, rhs=rhs@entry=0x16b40b8, result=...) at ../src/ast/rewriter/bv_rewriter.cpp:2074
#1  0x0000000000e7ed3b in bv_rewriter::mk_eq_core (this=this@entry=0x1654380, lhs=0x16b40b8, rhs=0x16149e8, result=...) at ../src/ast/rewriter/bv_rewriter.cpp:2118
#2  0x0000000000eab20c in reduce_app_core (result=..., args=0x16c3588, num=2, f=0x16ad9b8, this=0x1654308) at ../src/ast/rewriter/th_rewriter.cpp:173
#3  th_rewriter_cfg::reduce_app (this=0x1654308, f=0x16ad9b8, num=2, args=0x16c3588, result=..., result_pr=...) at ../src/ast/rewriter/th_rewriter.cpp:554
#4  0x0000000000eae001 in rewriter_tpl<th_rewriter_cfg>::process_app<false> (this=0x16541c8, t=0x163e6a8, fr=...) at ../src/ast/rewriter/rewriter_def.h:215
#5  0x0000000000eae4b5 in rewriter_tpl<th_rewriter_cfg>::resume_core<false> (this=0x16541c8, result=..., result_pr=...) at ../src/ast/rewriter/rewriter_def.h:602
#6  0x0000000000dc31e5 in propagate_values_tactic::operator()(ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal, 16u>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) ()
#7  0x0000000000e1a2ae in cleanup_tactical::operator()(ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal, 16u>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) ()
#8  0x0000000000e1ef61 in and_then_tactical::operator()(ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal, 16u>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) ()
#9  0x0000000000e1fa30 in and_then_tactical::operator()(ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal, 16u>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) ()
#10 0x0000000000e1fa30 in and_then_tactical::operator()(ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal, 16u>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) ()
#11 0x0000000000e1fa30 in and_then_tactical::operator()(ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal, 16u>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) ()
#12 0x0000000000e35364 in exec(tactic&, ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal, 16u>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) ()
#13 0x0000000000e357f9 in check_sat(tactic&, ref<goal>&, ref<model>&, obj_ref<app, ast_manager>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&, std::string&) ()
#14 0x0000000000ca18d7 in tactic2solver::check_sat_core(unsigned int, expr* const*) ()
#15 0x0000000000ca00d6 in solver_na2as::check_sat(unsigned int, expr* const*) ()
#16 0x0000000000ca404b in combined_solver::check_sat (this=0x16a0868, num_assumptions=<optimized out>, assumptions=0x16a2b90) at ../src/solver/combined_solver.cpp:235
#17 0x0000000000bead59 in cmd_context::check_sat (this=0x7fffffffc920, num_assumptions=0, assumptions=assumptions@entry=0x16a2b90)
    at ../src/cmd_context/cmd_context.cpp:1459
#18 0x0000000000bc8e38 in smt2::parser::parse_check_sat (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffbee0) at ../src/parsers/smt2/smt2parser.cpp:2170
#19 0x0000000000bd1d18 in parse_cmd (this=0x7fffffffbee0) at ../src/parsers/smt2/smt2parser.cpp:2500
#20 smt2::parser::operator() (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffbee0) at ../src/parsers/smt2/smt2parser.cpp:2655
#21 0x0000000000bc1d28 in parse_smt2_commands (ctx=..., is=..., interactive=<optimized out>, ps=...) at ../src/parsers/smt2/smt2parser.cpp:2704
#22 0x0000000000411ec5 in read_smtlib2_commands(char const*) ()
#23 0x0000000000412c83 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ../src/shell/main.cpp:342
```

Since this program works on one system (Linux v3.13) but fails on another (Linux v2.6.32), I presume this fault has something to do with the OS / configuration. Both systems run Z3 v4.4.2. On the system where Z3 crashes, the last Git commit ID is `a2fb4fc589d54ff776ec9b20a0849b9926fbb345` [January 4th].

Can someone please give me any hints about possible causes of the crash? Thanks much in advance!

Comment: In the last few days (and since a2f...) there have been a number of problems and fixes for  the floating-point code and the bit-vector code. Could you retry to see whether the latest version still has the bug?

Comment: Thanks @ChristophWintersteiger! While the previous program worked, Z3 segfaults in a different (bigger) program. The SMTLIB script is generated using the Z3 API, so I am unfortunately unable to extract the program.

    #1 0x00002b06fc578448 (libstdc++.so.6+0x5e448)
    #2 0x00002b06fdfbfda3 z3::context::check_error() const z3/include/z3++.h:158:0
    #3 0x00002b06fdfbfe09 z3::object::check_error() const z3/include/z3++.h:314:0
    #4 0x00002b06fdfd0b2f z3::solver::check() z3/include/z3++.h:1526:0